# View exported HTML

Tags: javascript

My example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ld4gy/

```
a.href = "data:text/html," + document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
```

Exports content by div id= content. However exported code does not look good. Everything is in one line. Please tips on how to fix it.

Comment: Nope. I tested your code and it works fine.

Comment: Please view on source code. Everything is in one line.

Comment: Everything is indeed in a single line, but what is the problem about it?

Comment: At higher code is unreadable. It's hard to edit it. Example in Notepad++

Comment: In this case it might help to indicate why you want to do this, as that would allow people answering to suggest solutions to your root cause problem, rather than your secondary level problem.

Comment: @user3583018 - If you really want to preserve the newlines, well here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/CwLYN/

Answer (score 0):

If you create your file using [the standard way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), the newlines are preserved:

```
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([document.getElementById("content").innerHTML], {type:"text/html"})
);
```

If you prefer a base64 string (for some reason), you can convert the blob to a string using a [`FileReader` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
reader.addEventListener("loadend", function(){ 
    console.log(reader.result);   //base64
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/CwLYN/